# C# - Saving a '.txt' File to the Project Root

Tags: c#, file, save

I have written some code which requires me to save a text file. However, I need to get it to save to my project root so anyone can access it, not just me.

Here's the method in question:

```
private void saveFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string fileName = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Please enter a save file name.", "Save Game");
            if (fileName.Equals(""))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid save file name.");
            }
            else
            {
                fileName = String.Concat(fileName, ".gls");
                MessageBox.Show("Saving to " + fileName);

                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(saveScene.ToString(), AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\" + fileName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(f);
        }
    }
```

Many people told me that using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` would contain the dynamic location of where the app was stored. However, when I execute this, nothing happens and no file is created.

Is there another way of doing this, or am I just using it completely wrong?

Comment: Your file is in the debug/bin location (the directory from where it ran). You didn't do anything wrong, just in the wrong place.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx) requires two parameters:
The first one is the FileName and the second is the content to write

```
File.WriteAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\" + fileName, 
                  saveScene.ToString());
```

Keep in mind however that writing to the current folder could be problematic if the user running your application has no write permission for the folder. (And in latest OS writing to the Program Files is very limited). If it is possible, change this location to the ones defined in [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enum

I wish also to suggest using the [System.IO.Path class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx) when you need to build paths and not a string concatenation where you use the very *'OS specific'* constant `"\"` to separate paths.

In your example I would write

```
 string destPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,fileName);
 File.WriteAllText(destPath, saveScene.ToString());
```

Comment: This is not the path to the project folder, it is to the bin catalogue

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What do you mean with _bin catalogue_?

Comment: The above solution writes to <myProjectFolder>/bin/<configuration>/ instead of just <myProjectFolder>

Comment: Do you have a WinForms/WPF application or a web one? Are you using .NET Core or the Framework.?

Answer (score 6):

no need for the extra `+ @"\"` just do:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + fileName
```

and replace the parameters

```
saveScene.ToString()
```

and

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + fileName
```

your code should be:

```
private void saveFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string fileName = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Please enter a save file name.", "Save Game");
            if (fileName.Equals(""))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid save file name.");
            }
            else
            {
                fileName = String.Concat(fileName, ".gls");
                MessageBox.Show("Saving to " + fileName);

                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory +  fileName, saveScene.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(f);
        }
    }
```

you can read on `File.WriteAllText` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx):

> Parameters
>
> ```
>    path Type: System.String 
>
>        The file to write to.  
>
>    contents Type: System.String
>
>        The string to write to the file.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` you can just do it this way:

```
    File.WriteLine("data\\Mytxt.txt", "Success!");
```

When you don't add anything, the basedirectory is automatically assumed.